# Class not found in Symfony 2.2

Tags: symfony, namespaces, symfony-2.2

I have a Symfony 2.2 project with just one app called *"Xedef"*. Inside that app folder, I've created a `Model` directory with some classes in it. I was hoping I could just define a namespace for that classes as declaring the namespace as:

```
namespace Xedef\Model;

class MyClass
{
    // ...
}
```

And then use them from, let's say, my controler just by "using" that namespaces as:

```
use Xedef\Model\MyClass;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function welcomeAction()
    {
        $myObj = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

But I had no luck. This results in the following error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Xedef\Model\MyClass' not found in 
>       /gitRepo/XedefApp/src/Xedef/MainBundle/Controller/HomeController.php

Oddly, I did this same thing in Sf 2.1 and I hadn't any troubles. Did something changed in 2.2?

Comment: Where is the model class? In the `app` directory?... it is autoloaded only if it's under the `src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autoload classes, you should place them in the `src` or `vendor` directory. You can also edit the `composer.json` file if you want to autoload the classes from another directory:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            ...
            "Xedef": "path/to/Xedef"
        }
    }
}
```